# Python: the return of the function is just returning only the first line of the opened file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-call

```
VERSION "3"


NS_ : 
NS_DESC_
CM_
BA_DEF_
BA_
VAL_
CAT_DEF_
CAT_
FILTER
BA_DEF_DEF_
EV_DATA_
ENVVAR_DATA_
SGTYPE_
SGTYPE_VAL_
BA_DEF_SGTYPE_
BA_SGTYPE_
SIG_TYPE_REF_
VAL_TABLE_
SIG_GROUP_
```

above is some text in a file, but after running it is just reading the first line even after using for loop what could be the reason as am new to this programming language please help me to get this?

```
def function(f):
lines = []
for Nrow,row in enumerate(f):
    lines = row.split(' ')
    return lines

with open('car.dbc', 'r') as f: #open the file
 contents = function(f)#put the lines to a variable (list).
 print(contents)
```

Comment: I suspect this is a whitespace issue but also suspect you haven't posted your actual whitespace

Comment: `lines` is the first line only (or the last line only if your indentation is different!), and `return` then terminates the function, instead `append` to lines and only `return` after the loop (or use `yield`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the whitespace in the question

```
lines = []
for Nrow,row in enumerate(f):
    lines = row.split(' ')
    return lines
```

will return on the first pass through the `for` loop.
You want to return when you have finished, appending (or extending) as you go:

```
lines = []
for Nrow,row in enumerate(f):
    lines.append(row.split(' '))
return lines
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, it is working fine and appending everything to a single list. I want to read each row or line in separate or individual list, like this-
['VERSION', '"3"\n']
['\n']
['\n']
['\tBU_BO_REL_\n']
['\tSG_MUL_VAL_\n']
['\n']
['BS_:\n']
['\n']
['BU_:\n']
['\n']
['\n']
['BO_', '2147483744', 'Car_Signals_0x60:', '21', 'Vector__XXX\n']
['', 'SG_', 'Zero_Byte', ':', '0|8@1+', '(1,0)', '[0|0]', '"NA"', 'Vector__XXX\n']
['', 'SG_', 'Sensor_Protocol_Version', ':', '8|8@1+', '(1,0)', '[3|3]', '"counter"', 'Vector__XXX\n']